# How to unable create a new record button from sub grid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, crm-ribbon-workbench

I want to prevent create a new record from my sub-grid of email entity (it's a custom view/subgrid), I tried to change it using ribbon workbench -> sub-grid ribbon, but I have many views to my Entity.

How do I know that I'm working on the right `addnew` button and not on unwanted subgrid or by mistake deleting the `addnew` button from all of my sub-grids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ribbon workbench or directly in ribbondiff xml, you can hide the (+) Add New button in all subgrids of that particular entity when customizing entity ribbon. It’s nothing to do with selected custom view or any particular form.

Make sure you hide the `+ ADD NEW {0}` button with CommandCore `AddNewRecordFromSubGridStandard`. Other one,  `+ NEW{0}` button is used within associated view.

Hide it so you can Unhide it again. Don’t delete it.

[image]

If you want to hide for some particular scenario, then probably some unsupported DOM manipulation can hide it in subgrid onload js.

Comment: Arun, I understand that if I hide that ADD NEW  in the ribbon all Entity sub grid will be effected, and I need to stop the user from creating a new record from a specific sug-grid, so hiding the button is not my answer in that case.

Comment: @Damkulul whatever you plan, thats going to be my last line answer. :)

Comment: :) what I was trying to say is that it's not possible to hide a ADD NEW button to a specific sub-grid

Comment: @Damkulul even disabling (+) is going to be thru DOM

Answer (score 0):

In version 8.1 the selector for the commands of a subgrid is `'#titleContainer_SUBGRIDNAMEHERE a'`.

If you try to do it `OnLoad`, I suggest you use `setInterval` to accomodate for the form load times (subgrids are loaded asynchronously).