# Dynamics CRM for mobile remove add button on a grid

Tags: mobile, dynamics-crm, dynamics365-app-mobile

How to remove add button from a grid on a form that is connected to the different entity in CRM? Here is the picture. Account entity is connected to the Case entity.

This + sign:

[image]

Comment: Which mobile app is this?

Comment: Dynamic CRM 365 for mobile phones,

Comment: This should work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49628631/7920473

Comment: Thank you I will try it on Monday and if it works  close the subject.

Comment: No because New button is already removed from the navbar, but it is still showing on the mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After month and a half of working on this issue I have finally got response from the Microsoft CRM support, removal of the sub-grid (+) button in not supported by this version of the mobile application. Only way to remove it is to disable the sub-grid on the mobile phone.
I hope that this will help someone in the future not to waste time.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: What version is this mobile app?

Comment: App version.-1 (-1,-1)

Answer (score 0):

Like explained in another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49628631/7920473), you can hide the subgrid (+) button using the Ribbon workbench.

Add the Case entity in a solution & open the solution in RWB. Right click & hide the subgrid button. This will hide it. You can come & unhide it again if you want.

[image]

Comment: This solution does not work for me because my team has already removed ADD NEW button but somehow it still shows on the mobile app grid.

Comment: @EmirSa Main grid or subgrids or associated grid?

Comment: This is on a sub - grid.

Comment: Your suggestion helped, I had to bring back the button then hide it again. thx