# Dynamics 365 hide New-Button in subgrid for activities

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

How can I hide the +NEW-Button in a subgrid of activities, when the parent records status is inactive? I tried already to hide this Button with RibbonWorkbench to see if hiding would generally work when I later implement a javascript hide-rule, but the +-Button is still visible. I tried to hide this button on the activitypointer as well as task entity but the +-Button is still visible.
Background: Customer should not be able to add new activities, when the paretn record's status is inactive.
I followed this tip [How to unable create a new record button from sub grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627030/how-to-unable-create-a-new-record-button-from-sub-grid) but withou success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Customer should not be able to add new activities, only view them

If you remove the create privilege for an entity in that user persona security role, then the **Add New [+]** ribbon button will be hidden automatically. That’s the right approach.

Comment: Thank you Arun. Based on your feedback I have updated my question to clarify the problem. But your answer is correct.

Comment: @SkippingAdi. I see your edit now, and this thread should be helpful for you - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/204006/can-we-get-around-the-limitation-of-appending-to-an-inactive-record/530128